# Any body worked on collecting feedback from testers using AppDistribution in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have set-up AppDistribution following the url -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/collect-feedback-from-testers

I am not sure how it will work for flutter.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Same here, i'm searching how to implemented in Flutter.